# No letterings in Blender

Tags: installation

I've installed Blender on an older machine. When I started it, I couldn't see any texts (see below).

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix it (e. g. change the font) ?

**Update 1 (03.09.2016 13:02 MSK):** This machine runs on *Windows 7 Starter Edition* with Russian locale. I'm using 32-bit version of Blender 2.77 (*blender-2.77a-windows32.msi*).

The graphics card is *Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3600 Series*.

Comment: Are drivers up to date?

Comment: @xlxs If you mean the graphics card drivers, then yes. Can my machine be too old for Blender?